# What is a SPPersistedUpgradableObject and the IUpgradable interface mean?

Tags: upgrade, database, cache

SPPersistedUpgradableObject is a SPPersistedObject that implements the IUpgradable interface. The MSDN is seriously lacks any documentation other than it:

> Provides members for managing an upgradable object

It seems to be related to caching and reloading the object from the database but i can't find confirmation of this anywhere.

So really my question do:

```
SPWebapplication wa = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication;
wa.Invalidate() //causes object to be reloaded from database on next access?
```

and

```
wa.Upgrade(); //causes object to be reloaded from the database?
```

actually do what i think they are doing?